# How to make functions queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the second function (blockdone) to run after the animation has finished running in the first function.

I know I can do this by putting blockdone in a callback on the animate method. But for reasons specific to the project I'm working on, I can't do this.

Is there some way to queue functions in someway in javaScript or jQuery?

https://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/mdawnrtq/

```
function blockmove(){
    $('.block').animate({top: '100px'},{duration: 1000} ).animate({width: '0'});
};
function blockdone(){
    $('p').text('Done');
};
blockmove();
blockdone();
```

Comment: *Why* can't you use the `.animate()` method's callback?  That is the solution here.  Without using the callback, there's no easy to know when the animation is done and when to call your next function.  Is this part of a jQuery plugin or something?  There should be no reason that you can't use the callback...

Comment: He did actually say he can't do that.

Comment: Calling `.animate()` twice will queue the second animation after the first one, so that actually makes sense, @RocketHazmat :-)

Comment: @Justastudent: Ah, yeah... that's right!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: How about a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that you know the selection on which the animations run, you can do this via the jQuery [`queue`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback) function. It literally allows you to specify a function that should be called when all other functions in the queue have completed.

You can specify a name of queue, as more than one queue can be created for a selection, but the default queue this function works on is the queue in which effects (`.animate()`) are stored. That is precisely what you want, hooray!

```js
function blockmove() {
  $('.block').animate({
    top: '100px'
  }, {
    duration: 1000
  }).animate({
    width: '0'
  });
};

function blockdone() {
  $('p').text('Done');
};

blockmove();
$('.block').queue(blockdone); // <-- CHANGED
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<p></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That's ideal, I didn't know about that function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not very ambitious, but since you know the duration of your animation, you could use `setTimeout` function to delay appearing the text?

```js
function blockmove(){
    $('.block').animate({top: '100px'}, {duration: 1000}).animate({width: '0'});
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('p').text('Done');
    }, 1400);
};

blockmove();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
</div>

<p></p>
```

Comment: I think you want to set a timeout of 1400ms then, because the second `.animate()` call also needs to finish (and the default duration is 400ms).

Comment: @Justastudent Thanks :-))

Answer (score 1):

I think you recive callback argument.

You have to change code below

```
function blockmove(callback){
    $('.block').animate({top: '100px'},{duration: 1000} ).animate({width: '0'},
      function(){
         if(typeof callback === "function") callback();
    });
};
```